# Add floor and ceiling to all values in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to add floor and ceiling of -3 and 3 to each element in a dataframe

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'a':[4,-3,6,2],'b':[1,2,3,4],'c':[11,-4.5,2,6]})
```

final result should show

```
   a  b  c
0  3  1  3
1 -3  2 -3
2  3  3  2
3  2  3  3
```

I did this by running over each columns and then using

```
df['a'].apply(lambda x: -3 if x<-3 else (3 if x>3 else x))
```

Is there a more elegant(python) way to do this

Comment: `df.clip(-3, 3)` ? Can't find a good dup, so posting an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`pd.DataFrame.clip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.clip.html):

```
df = df.clip(-3, 3).astype(int)

   a  b  c
0  3  1  3
1 -3  2 -3
2  3  3  2
3  2  3  3
```

The integer conversion is necessary as series `c` is originally a `float`. It appears `pd.DataFrame.clip` does not trigger re-casting of `dtypes`.